# Multiple join MySQL tables using a conditional clause

Tags: mysql

I have three tables which I need to join for educational purposes.

```
Table: users
 id | username | photo
  1 | me       | my_photo
  2 | my_friend| friend's photo
  3 | somebody | somebody`s photo

Table: chat
 mid | sender    | receiver | created
  1  | me        | my friend| 2016-12-27 09:32:2
  2  | my_friend | me       | Y-m-d h:i:s  
  3  | me        | somebody | 2016-12-27 09:32:2
  4  | somebody  | me       | Y-m-d h:i:s  

Table:favorites
  id | subscriber | subscribed_to
   1 | me         | my_friend
```

The desired output is

```
Conversations:
username  | photo            | created            | subscribed
me        | my friend's photo| 2016-12-27 09:32:2 | yes
my_friend | my foto          | Y-m-d h:i:s        | no
me        | somebody's foto  | 2016-12-27 09:32:2 | no
somebody  | my foto          | Y-m-d h:i:s        | no
```

For the moment I did the first part using that code:

```
$qmessage = mysql_query("
select c.*, u.photo
from chat c
join users u on u.username = c.sender
WHERE   (sender = '$login_session' AND receiver = '$uid') OR
        (sender = '$uid' AND receiver = '$login_session')
");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a series of joins is all you really need here.  The only part of the below query which might need explanation is the final left join.  I join the `chat` table to the `favorites` table using both the sender and receiver columns.  Then I use a `CASE` expression to check if a given record matched.  If so, then it assumed that there is a subscription and `'yes'` is printed, otherwise `'no'` is printed.

```
SELECT t1.sender AS username,
       COALESCE(t2.photo, 'NA') AS photo
       t1.created,
       CASE WHEN t3.subscriber IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS subscribed
FROM chat t1
LEFT JOIN users t2
    ON t1.receiver = t2.username
LEFT JOIN favorites t3
    ON t1.sender = t3.subscriber AND
       t1.receiver = t3.subscribed_to
```